# Docker errror: dotnet-file.dll does not exist

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core

I have successfully builded my app and there is image listed `my-app:2.7`
But when I try to run it error says:

Any idea where is wrong?

`docker run -it --rm -p 5000:80 --name my-app:2.7 uploadcore                                                        Unable to find image 'uploadcore:latest' locally docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for uploadcore, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied. See 'docker run --help'.`

`docker run -p 5000:80 my-app:2.7                                                                                   Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found. Possible reasons for this include: You misspelled a built-in dotnet command. You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-uploadcore.dll does not exist. You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.`

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/sdk:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 59518
EXPOSE 44364

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY UploadCore/UploadCore.csproj UploadCore/
RUN dotnet restore UploadCore/UploadCore.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/UploadCore
RUN dotnet build UploadCore.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish UploadCore.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "uploadcore.dll"]
```

Files structure

```
Context 
Controllers 
Migrations  
Models  
Properties  
Service 
Views
wwwroot
Program.cs
Startup.cs
UploadCore.csproj
appsettings.Development.json
appsettings.json
libman.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux is case sensitive, so your ENTRYPOINT has to be

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "UploadCore.dll"]
```

Your second `docker run` command works. You can add a container name with the `--name` option like this

```
docker run -p 5000:80 --name mycontainer my-app:2.7
```

The image name has to be the first parameter that isn't an option. In your first `docker run` command, the first one is `uploadcore`, so docker looks for an image called that and it can't find it.

Comment: ``docker run -it --rm -p 5000:80 --name UploadCore my-app:2.8`` resolved issue. Thank you dude!

Comment: Great :) If the answer solved your issue, can you mark the answer as accepted, please? That way other ppl can see that the question has been answered.